# Direct carrier billing android

Tags: android, billing

I want to sell some features in my android app with direct carrier billing payment and I don't want to publish in google play store.How to do ?
 please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for a direct carrier billing service provider. DCB service provider should support the carriers you want to support. Usually they inboard you in their system as a merchant so you can use their APIs to charge your users.

If you want to integrate with specific carrier, you can ask the carrier and they will redirect you to their partners.